# Laravel eloquent - get the most recent row when using WhereIn function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I currently have a function:

```
Score::whereIn('site_id', $sites)
      ->where('type', 1)
      ->avg('score');
```

But at the moment, as you can see, it averages out amongst *all* results within the Scores table. I want to only average out against the most recent row of each `$site_id` (the table may not have all $site_id's in the results though).

The table has a `created_at` column, which will determine which is the latest one by date/time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')` and limit your result with `take(15)`. That would take the 15 most recent records in your table.

```
Score::whereIn('site_id', $sites)
      ->where('type', 1)
      ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
      ->take(15)
      ->avg('score');
```

Docs on [take()](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_take) and [orderBy()](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orderBy).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Why use ->take(15)? The number of site_ids are dynamic, there could be 1 or 300. I would like to get the most recent row of all site_ids.

Comment: @Ben can you explain a little more? Maybe post your table's schema. You want to get the average score of (how many?) recent records where `site_id` is in `$sites` (which I assume is an array of IDs?)?

Comment: I want to get the average score of the latest row for each site_id. Yes, it's an array of IDs. so I want the SQL to get the latest row of each of the ID and average them out.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `groupBy`:

```
Score::whereIn('site_id', $sites)
      ->where('type', 1)
      ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
      ->groupBy('site_id')
      ->avg('score');
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Your suggested amendment won't get me the most recent row of each site though will it? It will just group the results by site_id?

Comment: Sorry, check the updated one. Forgot to add the orderBy. I checked my end and it worked.

Comment: Hello, no it didn't unfortunately, it still selects all the rows (even though it's grouped and ordered). I only want the most recent row of each site.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there's an easy way to do this with Laravel's active record style query builder.

All the times I've done something like this it has required a sub-query or a temporary table, because GROUP BY (in MySQL specifically) will honor the ORDER BY **AFTER** the grouping is complete, which means you can't guarantee pre-group that the value selected for the grouping is the one that conforms to your ORDER BY.

In this case I think you might actually need 2 sub-queries: the first to order the rows for grouping, the second to do the grouping so there is 1 row per site_id, and the final select to do the averaging. If you do just the first sub-query you will end up with an average for each individual site_id, instead of one average for all site_id's.

Here's an example query of what I think you're looking for:

```
SELECT AVG('score') FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY created_at DESC
    ) AS tbl GROUP BY site_id
) AS tbl2;
```

That's untested, but I think it's generally correct.

...all this assumes I've interpreted the question correctly, hopefully I did.

I wish I had a better suggestion than 2 sub-queries - if anyone else has a better way of doing this, I'd love to learn something new.

Now, doing this with Laravel's active record style query builder is something I'd have to go look up to see if it's even possible. Might need to just go run the raw query. But I figured I'd post the methodology to see if it's sound before digging in any further.